# Project management with bug tracking integrated

Tags: project-management, bug-tracking

Can someone recommend a hosted solution that answers the following requirements (I have seen other questions but none with these specific requests):

1. Project management with tasks, wiki, milestones
2. Bug tracking integrated
3. Collaborative - suitable for working with external developers
4. Subversion integration

I know Jira but it seems to be too complex and lacks on the collaboration

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) for project collaboration and bug tracking, and I think it meets all your requirements.

Comment: We eventually use jira hosted. Redmine is great if there was a hosted for that

Answer (score 0):

[CounterSoft Gemini](http://countersoft.com) may work for you.

The key issue is ensuring ALL team members (External or Internal) use the same tool (and stop using email!) for your project management.

Answer (score 0):

Check out []project-open[](http://www.project-open.com). It's an open-source project & portfolio management server that also includes a strong [ticket system](http://www.project-open.org/en/package_intranet_helpdesk) with dynamic fields, workflows etc. You can also integrate tickets into projects as WBA elements by including a "SLA" (service level agreement - this is specific type of project) as part of a larger projects. The SLA acts as a container for tickets, so that each project can have it's associated bug-tracker. ]po[ also support SVN integration, check http://www.project-open.org/en/package_intranet_cvs_integration for details.

Affiliation note: I'm a member of the ]po[ team.